# How to generate repeated code in Visual Studio for C++ using macros like #define in different files

Tags: c++, code-generation

I need to write code in one file, like:

```
void set_property_1();
void set_property_2();
void set_property_3();
...
void set_property_100();
```

And in another file with get_.

```
void get_property_1();
void get_property_2();
void get_property_3();
...
void get_property_100();
```

To make it just a bit faster i made a macro like

```
#define SET(num) void set_property_##num();
#define GET(num) void get_property_##num();
SET(1)
SET(2)
 ...
SET(10)

GET(1)
GET(2)
 ... 
GET(10)
```

It help just a bit.
The question is, how to generate code like this in more common way?
like

```
//pseudocode
//in third file
#define LIST = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

//In first file;
MACRO_FOR(AUTO L: LIST)SET(L)

//In second file;
MACRO_FOR(AUTO L: LIST)GET(L)
```

I`m using VisualStudio so may be there is some extension do that? Or some libraries? All what i find searchnig codegeneration c++ is information about low lvl stuff. Thanks for information.

Comment: There is  some macro magic you can use to achieve something similar. However, using it for only two method variants (set/get) and a list of numbers is probably taking longer thatn copy-pasting accordingly AND makes things practically unreadable. Please explain your goals you want to achieve. The question gives the impression that you want to save on typing, which in my opinion is not a good pay-off for the solution I can offer. If however you have more reasons than saving keystrokes, then it might be worth it. So please explain a little more on the background and goals.

Comment: Macros can only get you so far. At some point you need to break down and use a code generator. For example, a Python-based pre-build step. You can also write these in C++, but then you need a build-script for your pre-build build script and it can get kind of dizzying.

Comment: Why not using templates with a typed parameter? `template<int n> void set_property();`  and then usage `set_property<1>();`? The code is less. Not used functions are not instantiated. No macros.

Comment: What's wrong with `set_property(int);`?  You should set the compiler for high optimization, then print the assembly code for this function and where this function is called.  The compiler may already convert it to an inline operation.

Comment: I am really oversimplifying the question so as not to waste your time. But if you ask, I will explain. I have a [Qt project](https://github.com/ikvasir/Real_World_Algorithms/tree/master/AlgorithmsVisualisationQt) in which I need to connect signals from different properties (like RGB colors, different materials, etc...) into different slots to render. About 100 connections in each 3D scene. For example `connect (vertex_property, &property_material::property_material_ QPhongMaterial_ambient_signal, component_states_vertex, &component_states :: property_material_ QPhongMaterial_ambient _ slot)`

Comment: I've seen info about all the dangers of using  macros, but at my level of understanding of Qt, this is the best solution that I can do to implement connecting properties in the user interface with real objects in Qt. Templates in general nice, but how do i implement a templated version of Qt::connection() ... or a templated QWidget class? If there is an example? I would look. It looks like a pre-build C ++ script is a good point.  @tadman where i can read about it?

Comment: @ Thomas Matthews the 1,2,3 mean not int here it is part of function name. It may be "one","two", "three"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As result one function which do what i want. Generate all combinations without permutations from any number of sets of names to make unique not repetitive macros :D. I`v place it here. May be will helpfull for someone.
[The repo](https://github.com/ikvasir/macro_generator).

Usage in Visual Studio 19.

1. Build .exe from source.
2. Add Enviroment Varible to .exe file in Windows settings, i call it MACRO_GENERATOR.
3. In Visual Studio -> project Properties->Build Events-> Pre-Build Event add `call %MACRO_GENERATOR% $(ProjectDir)` and then all files in Project directory will be executed.
4. Add word `#GENERATE` at first string and use `//#define[]` and `//#for` like this:

```
#GENERATE
#define ADD_FUNC(NAME,PROPERTY) void f_##NAME##_##PROPERTY(){};
#define ADD_FUNC2(NAME,PROPERTY,WEIGHT) void f_##NAME##_##PROPERTY##_##WEIGHT();
#define ADD_FUNC3(NAME,PROPERTY,WEIGHT,KLMN) void f_##NAME##_##PROPERTY##_##WEIGHT##_##KLMN();

//#define[] NAME one,two
//#define[] COLOR red,green,blue
//#define[] WEIGHT low,big,very_nice
//#define[] KLMN K,L,M,N

//#for ADD_FUNC(NAME, COLOR)
//#for ADD_FUNC2(NAME,COLOR,WEIGHT)
//#for ADD_FUNC3(NAME,COLOR,WEIGHT,KLMN)

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

5. Press build and files in the project dir will be replaced with new with generated macros.

```
#define ADD_FUNC(NAME,PROPERTY) void f_##NAME##_##PROPERTY(){};
#define ADD_FUNC2(NAME,PROPERTY,WEIGHT) void f_##NAME##_##PROPERTY##_##WEIGHT();
#define ADD_FUNC3(NAME,PROPERTY,WEIGHT,KLMN) void f_##NAME##_##PROPERTY##_##WEIGHT##_##KLMN();

//NAME one,two
//COLOR red,green,blue
//WEIGHT low,big,very_nice
//KLMN K,L,M,N

// ADD_FUNC(NAME, COLOR) START GENERATION
 ADD_FUNC(one,red)
 ADD_FUNC(one,green)
 ADD_FUNC(one,blue)
 ADD_FUNC(two,red)
 ADD_FUNC(two,green)
 ADD_FUNC(two,blue)
// ADD_FUNC(NAME, COLOR) END GENERATION

// ADD_FUNC2(NAME,COLOR,WEIGHT) START GENERATION
 ADD_FUNC2(one,red,low)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,red,big)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,red,very_nice)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,green,low)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,green,big)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,green,very_nice)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,blue,low)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,blue,big)
 ADD_FUNC2(one,blue,very_nice)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,red,low)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,red,big)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,red,very_nice)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,green,low)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,green,big)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,green,very_nice)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,blue,low)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,blue,big)
 ADD_FUNC2(two,blue,very_nice)
// ADD_FUNC2(NAME,COLOR,WEIGHT) END GENERATION

// ADD_FUNC3(NAME,COLOR,WEIGHT,KLMN) START GENERATION
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,low,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,low,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,low,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,low,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,big,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,big,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,big,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,big,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,very_nice,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,very_nice,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,very_nice,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,red,very_nice,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,low,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,low,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,low,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,low,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,big,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,big,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,big,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,big,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,very_nice,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,very_nice,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,very_nice,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,green,very_nice,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,low,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,low,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,low,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,low,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,big,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,big,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,big,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,big,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,very_nice,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,very_nice,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,very_nice,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(one,blue,very_nice,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,low,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,low,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,low,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,low,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,big,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,big,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,big,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,big,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,very_nice,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,very_nice,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,very_nice,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,red,very_nice,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,low,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,low,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,low,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,low,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,big,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,big,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,big,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,big,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,very_nice,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,very_nice,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,very_nice,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,green,very_nice,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,low,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,low,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,low,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,low,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,big,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,big,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,big,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,big,N)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,very_nice,K)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,very_nice,L)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,very_nice,M)
 ADD_FUNC3(two,blue,very_nice,N)
// ADD_FUNC3(NAME,COLOR,WEIGHT,KLMN) END GENERATION

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

6. Be carefull! :) Only few checks added. The text of generation commands must be really closer to example.